# Best way to detect a continent to select best AWS S3 bucket

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to find the nearest bucket in Amazon S3 without using the GPS.

Is there any method in Obj-C to detect the current continent? 
Is there anything in the AWS framework?

My idea was to use the current country (from iphone preferences) to and make a list of continents with countries and then choose the correct bucket.

Another idea was to get the current timezone and check which timezone is closer to the timezone of the bucket.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to serve up static files from S3, this is all done automatically if you use CloudFront to serve content from a bucket.

CloudFront will look after serving the content from the nearest edge location to the client.